# Logging out from IdentityServer does not close the webview popup

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, openid-connect, oidc-client, identitymodel

I have used `IdentityModel.OidcClient` with a UWP app and connected to Azure AD. Login webview opens and automatically closes but the logout popup does not automatically close.

My implementation is based on [this](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/main/Uwp). When logout happens the final function call goes here but until the popup closes manually, execution hangs inside this `AuthenticateAsync` function call.

```
if (string.Equals(options.EndUrl, WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().AbsoluteUri, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                wabResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                    wabOptions, new Uri(options.StartUrl));
                //Execution returns here, once the popup closes manually.
            }
```

Logout happens correctly but the popup remains. Post logout URL was also configured correctly.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer.
You need to setup the `LogoutRequest` object and set the `IdentityToken` from the `LoginResult` object (Comes from the response of `LoginAsync` function) and send it with the `LogoutAsync` function.

```
var logoutRequest = new LogoutRequest
{
     IdTokenHint = _result.IdentityToken,
     BrowserDisplayMode = DisplayMode.Visible
};
await oidcClient.LogoutAsync(logoutRequest);
```

Comment: Inspired by this link https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/issues/119#issue-431447742